# R windows GUI halt execution when error

Tags: windows, r

One of my users is running a script in his R GUI in Windows. He takes the script itself and copy-paste it into the R console. If the user sets some incompatible parameters the script has errors but the rest of it executes giving the impression that everything has gone well. Is there some way such that the R session is terminated if an error is encountered? or any other way to stop execution without terminating the session as soon as any error is spotted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just rewrite your script as calls to one or more functions. If this is too much work, you can also just wrap lines of code in a `{...}` block. Execution will stop at the first encountered error.

Comment: I guess I will have to do that if I don't find something useful in options()

Answer (score 0):

```
halt = function() q('no')
options(error=halt)
```

will do the job

Comment: Won't that kill your session? You said you did not want that.

Comment: well I can call q() and then the user knows that there was some error. I really want something that pop's up

Comment: The problem is the rest of the pasted code will be used as if you typed it on your keyboard. For example, imagine that there is a blank line right below the code line that triggered an error: it will be as-if you pressed the ENTER key after the q() popped up, so it will definitely close your R session. Honestly, I think my solution is the way to go. If you want a popup for every error, you can still modify `options(error)` but it will not have the undesirable effect I described here.

Comment: I see, the thing is that this user in not completely naive and sometimes only copy-pastes a part of the code so the {...} would not work. I think will modify the `options(error)` more intelligently as you said, thanks

Comment: Well, copy-pasting is a bit of a naive approach in itself. Making your code available via function calls is by far my recommended approach. If the user finds that he/she only wants to run a portion of the code in a function's body, consider making a function just for that piece (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming)

Comment: Yeha I guess, I will have to wrap up in functions the chunks of code that he executes separately. That will be the best